# Transformers tokenizer attention mask for pytorch

Tags: python, pytorch, huggingface-transformers, huggingface

In my code I have:

```py
output = self.decoder(output, embedded, tgt_mask=attention_mask)
```

where

```py
decoder_layer = TransformerDecoderLayer(embedding_size, num_heads, hidden_size, dropout, batch_first=True)
self.decoder = TransformerDecoder(decoder_layer, 1)
```

I generate the attention mask using a huggingface's tokenizer:

```py
batch = tokenizer(example['text'], return_tensors="pt", truncation=True, max_length=1024, padding='max_length')
inputs = batch['input_ids']
attention_mask = batch['attention_mask']
```

Running it through the models fails on

`AssertionError: only bool and floating types of attn_mask are supported`

Changing the attention mask to `attention_mask = batch['attention_mask'] .bool()`

Causes

`RuntimeError: The shape of the 2D attn_mask is torch.Size([4, 1024]), but should be (1024, 1024)`

Any idea how I can use a huggingface tokenizer with my own pytorch module?

Answer (score 3):

Pytorchs `tgt_mask` is not the same as hf `attention_mask`. The latter indicates which tokens are padded:

```py
from transformers import BertTokenizer

t= BertTokenizer.from_pretrained("bert-base-cased")

encoded = t("this is a test", max_length=10, padding="max_length")
print(t.pad_token_id)
print(encoded.input_ids)
print(encoded.attention_mask)
```

Output:

```
0
[101, 1142, 1110, 170, 2774, 102, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Pytorchs equivalent to that is [tgt_key_padding_mask](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.TransformerDecoderLayer.html#torch.nn.TransformerDecoderLayer.forward).

The `tgt_mask` on the other hand serves a different purpose, it defines which token should attend to other tokens. For an NLP transformer decoder, this is usually used to prevent tokens to attend to future tokens (causal mask). In case this is your use case, you could also simply pass `tgt_is_causal=True` and PyTorch will create the `tgt_mask` for you.

Comment: Thanks @cronoik , another question I think you may help with is the memory argument in the case of a decoder-only model- do the tgt and memory should be the same input? Is I should also pass `memory_is_causal=True` as well right?